# Telegram app not rendering acestream link

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a bot which based on a word gives you a link to watch the sport events related. i.e. /search Madrid gives you links to watch real madrid or atletico de madrid matches. My problem is that most of this links are Acestream links (acestream://417b3b8...) and the app is not rendering it as a link. With the same code if the link is http://... is working fine. I tried with HTML and Markdown and the result is the same in both cases.

So:

```
[inline URL](r/http://www.example.com/)
```

Is rendering fine "inline URL"

```
[inline URL](acestream://6168476465858)
```

Is rendering "inline URL" but the link is not clickable, so there is no link.

Is there anything that I can do to show it as a link?

I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using this client to communicate with the API.

https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot

Thanks

Comment: That's the matter of how telegram clients render the content. Bot API accepts HTTP and tg:// URLs only. Maybe try instructing user to copy the URL (as text) to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Telegram doesn't turn ***acestream*** links into clickable links. A workaround is to use a URL shortening service to change the link into an HTTP one. You can also surround the link between two back quotes (`).  The official Android and iOS client copies the link to clipboard when user touches it.